# ERROR : No module named ""

Tags: python, pylint, pychecker

I got a small problem using pylint to check my python code. 
I use the opencv library in my code, which results in

```
E: 85: Module 'cv' has no 'MoveWindow' member
```

errors in my code. 
The reason for that is explained here : 
http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/78354

So I did just as they asked and created an astng_cv.py file in my code. 
I updated my PYTHONPATH so that he knows where my file is.

But when I try :

```
pylint --load-plugins astng_cv eagle_road.py
```

I keep having a :

```
ImportError: No module named astng_cv
```

error.

This is quite annoying and I don't really know what to do to solve the issue.

Would you have an idea?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: "ennuyeux" = "annoying", not "boring" in this context.

Comment: modified, thx btw. boring cause I spent two days searching for a solution would be ok ? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the astng_cv.py somewhere on your PYTHONPATH

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's the first thing I've done. I got some answers to write, but I have to wait for SO to let me put it ^^. 2 more hours to go

Comment: I think this one was long due :).

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't understand why pylint behaves that way. I want the custom checker for my project to live somewhere in my project's repo, and I want my checker enabled when users type just 'pylint --rcfile=X', using the standard project rcfile. I don't want to force a fiddly custom invocation on all users, that's easily forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems half solved here : http://www.logilab.org/5697

I can load my module in setting the PYTHONPATH directly :

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/jlengrand/bin/pypath pylint --load-plugins astng_cv tippy.py
```

But it is quite boring to have to set it each time.

The source seems to use imp.load_source, but I coulnd't really understand in which way :s .

Still searching then^^.

Comment: just put the plugin in a directory which is in sys.path. The site-packages directory is a good choice (assuming you have write access in there), otherwise configure your work environment to list ~/bin/pypath in PYTHONPATH once for all, using ~/.bashrc or your shell's equivalent.